# Internet is not connected in Mobile Hotspot

Tags: windows-10, android, mobile-hotspot

I used Mobile Hotspot feature of Windows 10 and I can connect to my network.
There is however no internet connection with clients which connect to this Mobile Hotspot.
How can I Troubleshoot this problem in android?

Comment: On your Windows 10 system, do you have internet access?

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321: Yes I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by going to this path on `regedit`:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\system\currentcontrolset\services\wlansvc\parameters\hostednetworksettings
```

and deleted HostedNetworkSettings DWORD key and again turned on Mobile Hotspot.[For more](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-turn-your-windows-10-pc-wireless-hotspot)

Also, I added a new Route Rule on our gateway

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following ways to troubleshoot the issue:

1. Create a mobile hotspot and share it, how to create a mobile hotspot and share it, we can refer this article: [How to turn your Windows 10 PC into a wireless hotspot](https://www.howtogeek.com/214080/how-to-turn-your-windows-pc-into-a-wi-fi-hotspot/)
2. Is there some settings like "Allow all Users" when creating hotspot, if so we can try to enable it, then all devices are able to pick up hotspot connection.
3. All the devices or only one android device cannot connect the network name of this hotspot? If all the devices can not connect to this hotspot, it may be a problem with creating or sharing hotspots, if only one android device can not connect this hotspot, it may be the settings problem with this android device.
4. Is there a device that can find the network name of this hotspot?
5. If a device discovers this hotspot, when we want to connect to this hotspot, is there a prompt to verify the network name and password?
6. If the android device can connect other wifi or other hotspots, it may be settings problem with this android device.
7. We can try to  add a hotspot network manually in the android devices, then we view if it can connect the mobile hotspot.